# How do I hide some objects on mobile platform builds

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have created the game for both PC and mobile devices like android, ios.
I have added some joystic components on the screen to help mobile users navigate the player.

The problem is that the joystic also appears on PC version as well.

How do I hide such components from being displayed on non mobile platforms of the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Detect if the platform is not a mobile device with [`Application.isMobilePlatform`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isMobilePlatform.html) in the `Awake` or `Start` function then deactivate the Joystick GameObject. Make sure that the joystick UI stuff has a parent GameObject. That parent GameObject is what you should deactivate.

```
public GameObject joyStick;

void Awake()
{
    if (!Application.isMobilePlatform)
    {
        joyStick.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Again, disable GameObject, not the component. That should also disable the children objects and the scripts attached to them.

**EDIT**:

> Thanks. I also want to the joystick script, gameobject to be excluded
>   in non mobile platform builds. Does this also take care of it?

No. If you want it to be excluded in the scene then after creating a parent object for the joystick, make it a prefab and then delete it from the scene or the Hierarchy tab. You can then instantiate a prefab only if this is a mobile device.

```
public GameObject canvas;
public GameObject joyStickPrefab;

void Awake()
{
    if (Application.isMobilePlatform)
    {
        Instantiate(joyStickPrefab, canvas.transform, false);
    }
}
```

Note that the prefab will still be included in the build but will not be in the scene or loaded in memory unless it's a mobile device. There is really [no way](https://support.unity3d.com/hc/en-us/articles/208456906-Excluding-Scripts-and-Assets-from-builds) of excluding prefabs or assets from build. You can exclude scripts based on platform with Unity's [preprocessor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) directives but you can't exclude assets which are the UI items from the jotystick.

Comment: Thanks. I also want to the joystick script, gameobject to be excluded in non mobile platform builds. Does this also take care of it?

Comment: Great explanation. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Answer on the Unity Q&A forums: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1426603/show-object-for-a-specific-platform-only.html

> Best solution that takes the least RAM is to use Prefabs to add objects in the scene by platform condition.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity scripting API provide a static class **[SystemInfo](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SystemInfo.html)**.

You can easily deactivate your object if your app is running on a Desktop.

```
if (SystemInfo.deviceType == DeviceType.Desktop)
    gameObject.SetActive(false);
```